# How could could I create a 2d tile map for my VisualStudio RPG game

Tags: visual-studio, file, dictionary, editor

The only method I thought would be to fill the form with pictureboxes, then adding your images from the tilesets, which would be ridiculously too long. I'd be grateful if someone could give me a tip on how to do this, I've tried to use Tiled, and others 2d map editors, but the problem is, I can't get the files to work with visual studio. Help please, even if it sounds dumb :/

Comment: Better game focused answers may be found at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Still, The fact it's a game doesn't matter, I just want to know if there's a way to put an homemade image made of tiles in the background of a form and at the same time being able to detect collisions with a picturebox. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Being a game does matter if you want to get answers from people that focus on games, performance, and have "been there done that". But yes, it can be looked at as a general programming question.